# C global anonymous struct / union

Tags: c, struct, arm, embedded, anonymous

I have a uint64 variable which often only requires high or low 32 bit access. I am using a 32-bit ARM Cortex M0, and to help with speed and I am trying to overlap the uint64 variable with two uint32 variables in C, using anonymous structures in the hope of avoiding pointer arithmetic to access members.

Is what I am trying to do possible? It could be that using a named union is just as fast, but now I'm just intrigued if it can be done without. The following does not compile successfully:

http://goo.gl/ejx37y

```
#include <stdint.h>

volatile union {
  uint64_t ab;
  struct { uint32_t a, b; };
};

int main(void)
{
  a = 1;
};
```

Comment: Can you access `ab`?

Comment: Show an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @MichaelWalz the question is about why it can't compile / how it can be made to compile, the given code constitutes an mcve.

Comment: Use shift/mask to access the two halves. Did you even check if these are less efficient than depending on omplementation details? It is very likely they are not (at least with optimisation on).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's simply not possible to do like that. A global variable (like the ones you declare in the header file) are not the same as members of an anonymous structure or union, that simply wont work.

And having anonymous structures or unions won't help with pointer arithmetic, the structure will still sit somewhere in memory, and the compiler uses offsets from the structures base-address to find out where the members are. However, since both the base-address and member offsets are know at time of compilation, the compiler will generally be able to generate code to access the member directly, just like any other variable. Look at the generated code if you are unsure.

So skip the nonsense with anonymous structures, define them properly in the header files, and declare variables of those structures in the header files too, while defining those variables in some source file.

So for the header file:

```
union you_union
{
    uint64_t ab;
    struct { uint32_t a, b; };
};

extern union your_union your_union;
```

And in a source file

```
union your_union your_union;
```

Comment: What is possible is to use `#define` something like `#define foo foo_union.ab`, `#define foo_high foo_union.a` and '`#define foo_low foo_union.b`.

Comment: @FUZxxl Of course it's possible, unless you have some other `foo` symbol. The nice thing about structures and unions is that they are scoped, you can have a member variable `foo` and some other non-member variable `foo` too.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg - Thanks, you're right, the anonymous union idea was a nonsense. I was just curious if it was possible. I checked code generated with a named union and the member offset does not add any extra instructions, so I'm happy with that solution.

Answer (score 6):

You define a union without an instance, which means that there is no union object containing the members. You could probably do something like this:

main.h:

```
typedef union {
  uint64_t ab;
  struct { uint32_t a, b; };
} u_t;

extern u_t u;
```

main.c:

```
u_t u = { .a = 1; };
```

And if you really wanted to (in main.h):

```
#define a u.a
#define b u.b
#define ab u.ab
```

If you do use `#define`s, be wary that they affect *any* declaration/use of the identifiers (a, b, ab), even those in a different scope. I recommend that instead you just access the values explictly via the `u` object (as `u.a`, `u.b`, `u.ab`).

I have removed `volatile` from the declarations because I highly doubt you really needed it. But you can certainly add it back if you wish.

(Note: the question originally had code split across two files, main.h and main.c. My answer correspondingly has code for two files. However, these could be combined into one easily).

Comment: The defines are nonsense at best. They hide the fact the "variables" are dependent, thus can easily result in coding errors which are hard to find. Also, as this is an embedded question, there is likely a reason OP added `volatile`. You should not assume he does not need it.

Comment: @olaf `extern volatile u_t u;` would do the trick, with a corresponding `volatile u_t u;` in the main.c.  However, if the OP is accessing compound data members like this in a case where `volatile` would be required, the chances are that a bit more than one keyword will be required to ensure correct behaviour of the code.

Comment: @Olaf I agree that adding `#defines` is not a good idea (hence "if you really wanted to"), but they give the effect that the OP specifically wanted. I suggest your misgivings should be directed to the OP. Regarding volatile, it rarely makes sense to declare a variable as volatile even in an embedded environment (at least, not without further steps such as causing a variable to be linked at a certain absolute address). A pointer-to-volatile on the other hand is reasonable. In any case, as I stated in the answer, OP is able to add the volatile back if s/he so wishes.

Comment: "it rarely makes sense to declare a variable as volatile even in an embedded environment"  That statement is just pure nonsense. There's numerous cases where it makes perfect sense. Enforce linking of variables that the compiler don't believe are used: eeprom constants, interrupt vector tables etc. Guarantee that the compiler reads the very same variables correctly. Enforce that register reads aren't optimized away. Ensure that variables shared with an ISR or callback aren't optimized incorrectly.  Preventing variables from getting optimized away while debugging. And so on.

Comment: @MikeofSST: What du you mean? Your comment is unclear to me.

Comment: @davmac: "t rarely makes sense to declare a variable as volatile even in an embedded environment ..." Sorry, but this is nonsense. Of course you have to know why you are using `volatile` and be aware of the implications. But it is nevertheless very much used in embedded systems. What do you mena by "an absolute address"? At run-time, every object has an absolute address. Even struct members of a defined variable have one: `address of the struct + offset`.

Comment: @davmac: However, as you introduced the macros (why not `inline` functions, btw?), you should have also made clar about their dangers. Even more, as a single-letter macro will replace **every** ocurence of that letter, including `#include`d headers! Not to mention you had to provide three macros per variables and the hiding of their relation.

Comment: @davmac - the volatile is because of interrupt access, but I should have removed it from the example as it wasn't relevant to the issue. Also just to clarify, I wasn't after a particular effect in the source code, but looking for efficiency in the generated code. Which it turns out wouldn't have been helped by the anonymous union even if it were legitimate.

Comment: @push2eject: If that is for interrupt access, it is even more important to differentiate between read/write and splitting the halves. Normally, you would read the variable as whole into a local variabel, then access the single fileds of that. Be careful when accessing a shared variable partially (the 64 bit access might already be a problem, as multi-word loads might be interrupted).

Comment: @Olaf @Lundin very well, I take back that `volatile` rarely makes sense in an embedded environment, you are correct that it can important when using the variable in ISRs and in some other cases. Some of these (eg register reads) generally require additional effort to make sure that the variable is linked at the appropriate absolute address (Olaf, by "absolute address" I meant "a particular absolute address" not just "any absolute address"). Olaf, I have added a warning against using `#define`. I re-iterate that I have already stated in my answer, _the OP can add back volatile if s/he wishes_.

Comment: It does not only affect "identifiers", but **any** text (well, except for comments(?)).

Comment: @Olaf "why not inline functions, btw?" - because they require different syntax. OP's question implies that s/he wishes to be able to use `a` and `b` to access the two halves as if they were variables (though OP has now clarified that this is not important to them). "It does not only affect "identifiers", but any text" - other than keywords and identifiers, there are not a great many cases where "any text" is subject to macro expansion, though, right?

Comment: (by which I mean: the intention was clearly to use `a`/`b`/`ab` in contexts where identifiers would be required).

Comment: @davmac: which is a nightmare of maintenance, as you do not see they are actually related. Every student or co-worker using such code would get into trouble if presenting such code. For the `inline`: I mean something like in my answer. Accessing the fields of a `volatile uint64_t` sepeartely is nonsense; either they are seperate, then a `struct`/array of two `uint32_t` is the better way, or they are related, the they always have to be accessed atomically as a whole, then it makes no sense to provide seperate access and functions can be use to get each half.

Comment: @Olaf I do not disagree with you, but this _is_ what OP was asking for. You know that my answer at this point recommends against using the `#define`. And the fact that "accessing the fields of a volatile uint64_t sepeartely is nonsense" might be true (though who's to say what quirky hardware might require this in some circumstance) ; I'm just trying to show a way that OP can achieve what OP said they wanted to achieve.

Comment: @davmac: I already removed my DV some comments ago:-) I wrote all this in my answer, but problem with noobs is they try to optimize and reinvent the wheel once again, thinking they can outsmart the compiler. To me it looks as if every new generation has to run into the same tarpits again - just at a higher level.

Comment: @Olaf, no problem, I know exactly what you mean.

Comment: @Olaf I only meant that when the `volatile` keyword is required, so that the CPU reads or writes the affected memory on every access, it usually implies that the value can be changed asynchronously by hardware, ISRs or similar.  Hence the parts of the `struct` need to be accessed atomically and extra code would be required to achieve that.  Beyond the scope of this question, but relevant to your first comment that the OP probably included `volatile` for a specific reason.

Answer (score 4):

There is actually little to no reason to use a union. Instead, use shift/mask, possibly in `inline` functions to extract the two halves:

```
static inline uint32_t upper(uint64_t val)
    { return (uint32_t)(val >> 32); }

static inline uint32_t lower(uint64_t val)
    { return (uint32_t)val; }
```

This will be very likely optimized by the compiler to the same code as the union-approach.

However, as you are refering to *anonymous struct/union **members***: Omitting the name is a feature of the struct/union which **includes** the member, not the member being a struct/union. So you can use:

```
union {
    uint64_t v64;
    struct {
        uint32_t l32;
        uint32_t h32;
    };  // here the name can been omitted
} my_flex_var;
```

Problems are:

- non-portable, possibly depends on ABI/PCS used (although the AAPCS is quite clear about this, there are others which might differ).
- depends on little endian (some ARM CPUs/implementations allow for big-endian, too).
- cannot be used on instances defined already as `uint64_t`.
- less explicit than function loads.
- might add overhead for compound types (non-register argument passing, placement on stack instead of registers, etc.

Normal usage of a volatile is to load/store it always with full size. If that is not the case, a race condition might uccur and you are in the world of locking/mutex, etc. which makes things **very** much more complicated. If the two fields are only loosely related, you are very likely better off with two 32 bit variables or a `struct` thereof.

Typical usage:

```
volatile uint64_t v64;

void int_handler(void)
{
    uint64_t vt = v64;

    uint32_t l = lower(vt);
    uint32_t h = higher(vt);

}
```

This ensures the variable is read only once. With a proper compiler, the assignments to `l`, `h` will not generate any code, but the registers with `vt` are used. That depends, of course on your code, but even **if** there is some overhead, that will be negligible.

(Sitenote: This is from my own practise as a long time embedded programmer)

Comment: I'll try it out and compare results, but as much as I normally love shifts and masks I can't see how they could be as efficient in this case, especially with the variable being volatile. `status.hi32 |= 0x00000001u;` only requires 32-bit operations, whereas it would need more loads and stores to deal with a volatile uint64, surely? But I'll try it out and see what magic the compiler can do... :-)

Comment: @push2eject: I updated the answer to reflext yur comment. Fell free to read on. And examine the assembler code (with optimization).

Comment: I hear and agree with everything you say for read access, but I don't think the shifts and masks work as well for writing. See my own answer below, with compiler output (at max optimisation). Thanks for your clarification re anonymous members - I didn't have a proper understanding of this, which was what had me head-scratching in the first place...

Answer (score 3):

No, of course you can't access members of a non-instantiated type. Where would the data be stored?

You should just make the `union` visible, and trust the compiler to generate efficient accesses. I don't think there's going to be any "pointer arithmetic", at least not at run-time.

Answer (score 0):

You could get fancy and use assembly to achieve what you want, or use C++.

In assembly

```
                EXPORT AB
                EXPORT A
                EXPORT B
AB
A               SPACE 4
B               SPACE 4
```

In C:

```
extern uint64_t AB;
extern uint32_t A;
extern uint32_t B;
```

Then do what you want.

In C++, something like this:

```
union MyUnionType
{
    uint64_t ab;
    struct 
    {
        uint32_t a;
        uint32_t b;
    };
} ;

MyUnionType MyUnion;

uint64_t &ab = MyUnion.ab;
uint32_t &a  = MyUnion.a;
uint32_t &b  = MyUnion.b;
```

But, to be honest, this is all wasted effort.   Accessing `a` or `MyUnion.a` is going to have the same code generated by the compiler.  It knows the size and offsets of everything, so it's not going to calculate anything at runtime, but just load from the right address it knows ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify what I've learned:

It turns out C doesn't allow global members of anonymous structs/unions. Oh well. But using named structs/unions generates efficient code anyway, as the member offset is known at compile time and can be added without incurring extra instructions.

Regarding using shifts & masks instead of a union, this may work well for reads, but for writes it results in extra instructions (9 vs 5) and pointless accesses to the low uint32. On the other hand, it is more endian portable than a union, but that isn't important in my application.

```
union status {
   struct { uint32_t user, system; };
   uint64_t all;
};
volatile union status status;

status.system |= 1u;                // write to high uint32 member directly
2301        movs r3, #1
4A02        ldr r2, 0x00002910
6851        ldr r1, [r2, #4]
430B        orrs r3, r1
6053        str r3, [r2, #4]

status.all |= ((uint64_t)1)<<32;    // write to full uint64
2001        movs r0, #1
4905        ldr r1, 0x00002910
680C        ldr r4, [r1]
684D        ldr r5, [r1, #4]
4328        orrs r0, r5
1C22        adds r2, r4, #0
1C03        adds r3, r0, #0
600A        str r2, [r1]            // this is not atomic, and pointless
604B        str r3, [r1, #4]        // this is the important part
```

Comment: What is a "global member"? There are only global variables, the file is not a `struct` and obviously not a `union`.

Comment: Ok, just had a peek into the M0 instruction set. I confused with the M3/4. The M0 does not even have load/store double instructions, so a 64 bit load/store will **never** be atomic. Anyway, this has nothing to do with using a `union` or the right-side operations (why should it?). Either way, as you seem to have different fields in both values, combining them to a 64 bit value is pointless anyway. Primary question is: Why do you **need** explicit 64 bit operations? Unless you need 64 bit arithmetics, they are pointless.

Comment: It's important to recognize that the inefficient code for the shift-based store is a limitation of the compiler that you are using. It's perfectly possible for an optimising  compiler to produce the same instructions regardless of which technique you used. So, while what you have written is true in your case right now, it is not a general truth.

Answer (score 0):

The question is about C, but it should probably be mentioned that this syntax (with `static`) is supported in C++ mode
in clang and Visual Studio, but not in gcc (gcc doesn't support unnamed structs in global unnamed unions):

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

static union {
    uint32_t ab;
    struct { uint16_t a, b; };
};

int main()
{
    ab = 0x44332211;
    printf("%x", a);
}
```

[Run it with clang](https://tio.run/##VYzLCoMwEEX3@YrBUlCwpYnSTdr@SpnEPgI2BjMBQfrt6airXmZ1ztxrQzjYHv0r553ztk/dAy6ROjcc3zfxjzwtTERCchaSd4OHWQAnsWvUnQCNXkGkMVmCeTXyvJgajIavFnyCIXzQ@bIS2wAauMJpatumUUrKbSSM/Pcsi/1U1IAVV3P@AQ)

Comment: *unnamed structs in global unnamed unions*  Oooof. That's a solution in search of a problem that also would cause all kinds of O&M nightmares.  "Where in the world did this variable come from?!?!"