# Force compiler/linker to group variables (physically in consecutive RAM locations) as defined

Tags: c, gcc

How can I force the complier (with option switches I assume) to group variables together in physical, consecutive RAM locations in the order defined ? I don't really care where it starts (that is - where it puts `MinWaitTime`. However, `FaultCode` must be located immediately after `MinWaitTime` in RAM. It cannot put it somewhere else.

I thought of creating a section, but this will only guarantee that they are placed together, and not necessarily in the order they were defined.

I know that I could create and array to force the issue, but I would like to avoid it.

Any suggestions ?

For instance if `MinWaitTime` was at address 0x20000000, I want `FaultCode` defined at 0x20000002, and every other variable in that order.

```
unsigned short  MinWaitTime;        // reg 450

unsigned short  FaultCode;          // reg 451

unsigned short  FaultReg1;          // reg 452

unsigned short  FaultReg2;          // reg 453

unsigned short  Reserved2;          // reg 454

unsigned short  Reserved3;          // reg 455

unsigned short  SystemStatusReg1;   // reg 456

unsigned short  SystemStatusReg2;   // reg 457
```

The complier is GCC.

Comment: Generally - you can't. Some compilers might have options. But I don't think `gcc` has.

Comment: You need an array.

Comment: What do you think they need to be stored that way?

Comment: What do you have against arrays?

Comment: ...or *packed* structures, which are *still* supported by gcc.

Comment: How about a union of an array and a series of unsigned shorts?

Comment: @ChristianGibbons ...which still has to be packed...

Comment: @EugeneSh. Hmm, yes, I guess it does.  Mind blanked on the fact that the series of unsigned shorts would need to be in a struct regardless.

Comment: They are all shorts. Packing is not going to make a difference (on any normal architecture).

Comment: Usually a struct will get you what you want. To make sure add an assertion, possibly a static assertion.

Comment: This all but screams ["XY problem!"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)  What *problem* are you trying to solve?

Comment: To begin with, doesn't the compiler already place them in the order in which they occur in the source? And, you should be able to either tell the linker something relevant, or go via the assembler step and edit the assembler file.

Comment: @ArndtJonasson: The compiler isn't required to lay variables out in the same order they are declared - in fact, there may be good reasons for *not* doing so (minimize space lost to alignment restrictions, for example).  If you want to *guarantee* an ordering in memory, you have to use an array or a struct (or some implementation-specific magic)

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions and comments. I decided to go with an array, then define a name for each array element for ease of access. Since all the elements were unsigned shorts, I was hoping that there was a way for to force the compiler/linker to group them in order. But hope is never a good plan. Thanks again !

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways to approach this.

### struct + macros

The easiest way is just to use a struct, possibly with macros:

```
struct {
    unsigned short MinWaitTime;
    unsigned short FaultCode;
    ...
} vars;

#define MinWaitTime (vars.MinWaitTime)
#define FaultCode (vars.FaultCode)
...
```

This is nice because this is exactly what a struct is designed to do, but the macros are not great.

In theory, a "[global anonymous struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32906637/c-global-anonymous-struct-union)" would make it so you can do this without macros but this does not exist.

**Opinion:** I would use the struct, but without the macros.

### assembly

Another way you can do this is with a little help from assembly. You can create a separate assembly source file with the following code:

```
    .data
    .align 2

    .globl MinWaitTime
MinWaitTime:
    .zero 2

    .globl FaultCode
FaultCode:
    .zero 2

    .globl FaultReg1
FaultReg1:
    .zero 2

    .globl FaultReg2
FaultReg2:
    .zero 2
```

This defines the variables at consecutive addresses. You can then access them from C, just declare them extern somewhere in your C source code:

```
extern unsigned short MinWaitTime;
extern unsigned short FaultCode;
extern unsigned short FaultReg1;
extern unsigned short FaultReg2;
```

The `extern` is only necessary so that you don't get duplicate definitions.

Then, compile and link the C and assembly files together.

#### Notes

Note that we are explicitly not concerned with portability here.