# What is the difference between initializing a struct vs anonymous struct?

Tags: c, gcc, optimization, struct, unions

Consider the following code:

```
typedef struct {
  uint32_t a : 1;
  uint32_t b : 1;
  uint32_t c : 30;
} Foo1;

void Fun1(void) {
  volatile Foo1 foo = (Foo1) {.a = 1, .b = 1, .c = 1};
}
```

This general pattern comes up quite a bit when using bit fields to punch registers in embedded applications. Using a recent ARM gcc compiler (e.g. gcc 8.2 or gcc 7.3) with `-O3` and `-std=c11`, I get the following assembly:

```
  sub sp, sp, #8
  movs r3, #7
  str r3, [sp, #4]
  add sp, sp, #8
  bx lr
```

This is pretty much exactly what you want and expect; `Foo` is not volatile, so the initialization of each bit can be combined together into the literal `0x7` before finally being stored to the volatile variable (register) `foo`.

However, it's convenient to be able to manipulate the raw contents of the entire register which gives rise to an anonymous implementation of the bit field:

```
typedef union {
  struct {
    uint32_t a : 1;
    uint32_t b : 1;
    uint32_t c : 30;
  };
  uint32_t raw;
} Foo2;

void Fun2(void) {
  volatile Foo2 foo = (Foo2) {.a = 1, .b = 1, .c = 1};
}
```

Unfortunately, the resulting assembly is not so optimized:

```
  sub sp, sp, #8
  ldr r3, [sp, #4]
  orr r3, r3, #1
  str r3, [sp, #4]
  ldr r3, [sp, #4]
  orr r3, r3, #2
  str r3, [sp, #4]
  ldr r3, [sp, #4]
  and r3, r3, #7
  orr r3, r3, #4
  str r3, [sp, #4]
  add sp, sp, #8
  bx lr
```

For a densely packed register, a read-modify-write of each bit can get... expensive.

What's special about the union / anonymous struct that prevents gcc from optimizing the initialization like the pure struct?

Comment: Look at answer toward the bottom here [C global anonymous struct / union](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32906637/c-global-anonymous-struct-union). In the union, it must provide offsets for both the struct and `uint32_t` and then bitfield address to the anonymous struct on top of that. The named struct simply provides bitfield access. The jist I get is that gcc can optimize named structs more easily than anonymous structs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C global anonymous struct / union](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32906637/c-global-anonymous-struct-union)

Answer (score 1):

I hope I could answer your question. The problem is GCC compiler has some predefined rules about C to Assembly conversions, and when you make an `union` of one `struct` and one `uint32_t` it doesn't have a predefined pattern and that's why the resulting assembly it's not optimized as well as the first example.

I suggest you to use casting to solve the problem.

```
typedef struct {
  uint32_t a : 1;
  uint32_t b : 1;
  uint32_t c : 30;
} Foo1;

void Fun1(void) {
  volatile Foo1 foo = (Foo1) {.a = 1, .b = 1, .c = 1};
  volatile uint32_t rawA = *((uint32_t *) &foo);
  volatile uint32_t rawB = *((uint32_t *) &foo + sizeof(uint32_t);
}
```